# Unexpected identifier 'getProject'. Expected ';' after async variable declaration

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await

I have the following JS on a web page.

```
<script async type="module">
import {projectCode} from "./assets/js/config.js";
import {getProject} from "./assets/js/saleproject.js";
import {getAccount} from "./assets/js/account.js";
import Vue from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.esm.browser.js'

let projectData = await getProject(projectCode);

...

</script>
```

The data is then stored in Vue.js to render a page. For further context the above references the following code in a seperate file:

```
import { server } from './config.js';

export async function getProject(projectCode) {
    const response = await fetch(server + '/saleproject/GetByCode/' + projectCode);
    const projectData = await response.json();
    return projectData;
}
```

Everything works fine, except on iPhones, where I get the following error which breaks my code and prevents Vue.js from rendering the page:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'getProject'. Expected ';' after variable declaration.
```

I have tried wrapping it in an async function like this, but still had no luck:

```
(async function () {
    let projectData = await getProject(projectCode);
}())
```

Which returns a Vue.js related error:

```
Error in data(): "ReferenceError: projectData is not defined"
```

I'm not sure what needs to be changed for this to work correctly on iPhones (works fine in desktop Safari)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempted solution is correct, the only issue is that the `let` is scoped to the IIFE scope.

Re-write your code as follows:

```js
getProject(projectCode).then(projectData => {
 // All code goes here
});
```

The issue original is caused by a lack of top-level await support.